# Open a new tab in a private window in Safari using applescript

Tags: safari, applescript, workflow, alfred

Actually I developed an workflow for Alfred. It suppose whatever you search to open in a new private window in Safari, and it work as it supposed.. but the problem is, it open every search in a new private window, and I want the first search to open a new private window, and start with the next one, just to open new tabs inside that window. Hope I was clear enough, I am kinda new, and I do my best to learn, so any suggestion are very welcomed. Here is what I got so far:

```
tell application "System Events" to ¬
       click menu item "New Private Window" of ¬
        menu "File" of menu bar 1 of ¬
        application process "Safari"
tell application "Safari" to ¬
            set URL of current tab of ¬
        front window to "https://duckduckgo.com/?q={query}&t=h_&ia=web"


tell application "System Events" to ¬
       click menu item "New Tab" of ¬
        menu "File" of menu bar 1 of ¬
        application process "Safari"
tell application "Safari" to ¬
            set URL of current tab of ¬
        front window to "https://duckduckgo.com/?q={query}&t=h_&ia=web"
```

P.S The part 2 of the code, is just my draft, technically that part open a new tab inside the window, but is just a duplicate of the initial search.

Answer (score 1):

Store the private window in a variable so that it can be accessed later:

```
property privyWindow : missing value

tell application "Safari"
    -- a set of tests to make sure the window is present and valid
    set noWindow to (privyWindow is missing value) or not (exists privyWindow) or (current tab of privyWindow is missing value)
end tell
if noWindow is true then
    -- make new private window, and get its first tab
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Safari"
            click menu item "New Private Window" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
        end tell
    end tell
    tell application "Safari"
        set privyWindow to first window
        set activeTab to first tab of privyWindow
    end tell
else
    -- retrieve stored window and add a new tab to it
    tell application "Safari"
        set activeTab to make new tab in privyWindow
    end tell
end if

-- open the url in the specified tab
tell application "Safari"
    set URL of activeTab to "https://duckduckgo.com/?q={query}&t=h_&ia=web"
end tell
```

Comment: So how are you going to handle when the _private window_ has been _closed_ and the _script_ is run again? As coded and under the expressed condition  it will error with e.g.: Safari got an error: Can’t get window id 5226.

Comment: @user3439894: Ah, didn't consider that issue. Code revised in answer.

Comment: Hi Ted, thank you a lot for your help. 
But unfortunately it still opens every times in a new private window.

Comment: @BogdanDuduia: the `property` variable will reset itself every time you recompile the the script (or sometimes if you're doing other things, like running this through `osascript` or from an app). If it's opening a window every time, that means you're doing something offbeat that you haven't specified in your question. I can only test for what what you tell me.